# Optimizing scaled video for quality and performance

Tags: scale

I'm using obs to live stream a number of cameras, and pc sources. All are at 1080, but I want to resize some for picture in picture.

Keeping the aspect ratio the same, is it better, for image quality and reducing processor demands, to use resolutions that are fractions of 1080, for example half, which is 960x540, or quater 480 x 270? Or will it not make much difference?